# Unable to fetch XML Element using XML path config through Logstash xml filter plugin

Tags: xml, logstash

I am pulling some stream of XML files from Kafka topic and trying to fetch one of the element of XML file through Logstash using XML filter plugin but unable to do so ; mentioning details below ;

XML block of stream :

```
`<?xml v="1.0" enc="UF-8"?> 
   <\ns0:LogRequest xmlns:ns0="http://SOME/URL/SOME.xsd"> 
   <\ns1:Header xmlns:ns1="http://SOME/URL/SOME1.xsd">
   <\ns1:ApplicationID>ABC<\/ns1:ApplicationID>
   <\ns1:ComponentName>XYZ<\/ns1:ComponentName>
   <\ns1:Hostname>MYHOST<\/ns1:Hostname>
   <\ns1:Timestamp>2017-02-27T23:07:44.318+05:30<\/ns1:Timestamp>
   <\ns1:TransactionDomain>Some Domain <\/ns1:TransactionDomain> 
   <\ns1:TransactionType>Some Type<\/ns1:TransactionType>
   <\ns1:Message>Some Message <\/ns1:Message>
   <\ns1:AltKey>\n 
   <\ns1:AltKeyName>LOG<\/ns1:Alt\KeyName>
   <\ns1:AltKeyValue>Some Key <\/ns1:AltKeyValue>\n 
   <\TimeDuration>1488217064317<\/TimeDuration>\n 
   <\Status>Some Status <\/Status>\n 
   <\Audit>true\n<\/ns0:LogRequest>`
```

I want to fetch the value of "Timestamp" and save it as new field but unable to do so ,

Logstash.conf:

```
    filter {

        xml {
          store_xml => "false"
          remove_namespaces => "false"
          source => "message"
          namespaces => {
              "ns0" => "http://SOME/URL/SOME.xsd"
              "ns1" => "http://SOME/URL/SOME1.xsd"
            }
           xpath => [ "/ns0:LogRequest/ns1:Timestamp/text()", "mytime" ]

        }

        mutate {
                                #convert => { "mytime" => "string" }
                                add_field => ["time_stamp", "%{mytime}"]
              }

    }

Expected Output :

"time_stamp" => "2017-02-27T23:07:44.318+05:30"

Actual/Present Output : 
"time_stamp" => "%{mytime}"

Any help will be really appreciated !!
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, i resolved this issue by doing following steps ,

- removed the namespaces from Logstash processing ;
- updated the X-path for Timestamp element;

so now my configuration look like ,

```
filter {

xml {
  store_xml => "false"
  remove_namespaces => "true"
  source => "message"
   xpath =>["//[localname()='LogRequest']/*/[localname()='Timestamp']/text()", "mytime" ]

     }
```

}